# Hide Adsense ad space in android app webview by its id?

Tags: android, wordpress, adsense

I want to hide space caused by the google `AdSense` ads in the android app while fetching data from its WordPress site through `WebView`. My Code is:

```
public class PostViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = PostViewActivity.class.getSimpleName();
public static final String TAG_SEL_POST_ID = "post_id";
public static final String TAG_SEL_POST_TITLE = "post_title";
public static final String TAG_SEL_POST_IMAGE = "post_image";
private String commentsNumber;


private String selectedPostID, selectedPostTitle;
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
private ImageButton fab;
private TextView post_name;
private TextView post_content;
private TextView post_author;
private ImageView postImageView;
private String post_image, objURL, objTitle;
private Integer commentsCount;
private TextView timestamp;
private NetworkImageView profilePic;
private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
private WebView post_contentHTML;
private Boolean user_can_comment = true;

private Spanned spannedContent;
private ProgressBar pbLoader;
private LinearLayout llayout;

private Integer OC = 0;
String html;
Gson gson;
Map<String, Object> mapPost;
Map<String, Object> mapTitle;
Map<String, Object> mapContent;
//----------Exit and Banner Ad----------------------------------
private InterstitialAd interstitial;
private AdView mAdView,mAdView1;

private Toolbar toolbar;
String URL ="http://www.asiannews.co.in/_STORY_ID_/";

public static void navigate(AppCompatActivity activity, View transitionImage, Post post) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, PostViewActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(TAG_SEL_POST_IMAGE, post.getImge());
    intent.putExtra(TAG_SEL_POST_TITLE, post.getName());

    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity, transitionImage, TAG_SEL_POST_IMAGE);
    ActivityCompat.startActivity(activity, intent, options.toBundle());
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
    // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
    // killed and restarted.
    savedInstanceState.putString(TAG_SEL_POST_ID, selectedPostID);
    savedInstanceState.putString(TAG_SEL_POST_TITLE, selectedPostTitle);
    Log.d(TAG, savedInstanceState.toString());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Restored: " + savedInstanceState.toString());
    selectedPostID = (String) savedInstanceState.getString(TAG_SEL_POST_ID);
    selectedPostTitle = (String) savedInstanceState.getString(TAG_SEL_POST_TITLE);
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //Get a Tracker (should auto-report)
    if (Const.Analytics_ACTIVE) {
        AnalyticsUtil.sendScreenName(this, TAG);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    initActivityTransitions();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_view);

    //Forcing RTL Layout, If Supports and Enabled from Const file
    Utils.forceRTLIfSupported(this);

    ActivityCompat.postponeEnterTransition(this);
    final String id = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id");
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });



    //Get and Set the Post Title
    String itemTitle = getIntent().getStringExtra(TAG_SEL_POST_TITLE);
    setTitle(Html.fromHtml(itemTitle));

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        if (getIntent().getExtras() == null) {
            selectedPostID = null;
            selectedPostTitle = "Unknown Error";
        } else {
            selectedPostID = getIntent().getExtras().getString(TAG_SEL_POST_ID);
            selectedPostTitle = getIntent().getExtras().getString(TAG_SEL_POST_TITLE);
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Resume: " + savedInstanceState.toString());
        selectedPostID = (String) savedInstanceState.getString(TAG_SEL_POST_ID);
        selectedPostTitle = (String) savedInstanceState.getString(TAG_SEL_POST_TITLE);
        /*selectedPostID = (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(TAG_SEL_POST_ID);
        selectedPostTitle = (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(TAG_SEL_POST_TITLE);*/

    }

    //Setting up Fields Display
    fab = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    post_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    timestamp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/GenR102.ttf");
    post_name.setTypeface(font);


    float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int leftPadding = (int) (20 * density);
    Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
    if (ViewCompat.getLayoutDirection(post_name) == ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL) {
        //post_name.setPadding(leftPadding,R.dimen.spacing_large,0,0);
        post_name.setPadding(leftPadding, 0, 0, 0);
    } else {
        post_name.setPadding(0, 0, leftPadding, 0);
    }


    post_content = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
    post_contentHTML=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.descriptionHTML);
    String post_con = "<!DOCTYPE html>" +
            "<html lang=\"en\">" +
            "  <head>" +
            "    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">" +
            "  </head>" +
            " <body>"+ "<script>" +
            "<ins>" +"</ins>" +
            "</script>"+"<script>"+
            "</script>"
            +"#content" +
            "  </body>" +
            "</html>" ;
    html= "<html><body style='margin:0;padding:0;'><script type='text/javascript' src='http://asiannews.co.in/myads.html'></script></body></html>";


    if (!Const.ShowPostAsWebView) {
        post_content.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        Typeface font_postcontent = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OSRegular.ttf");
        post_content.setTypeface(font_postcontent);
          String url = "http://www.asiannews.co.in/bp4a-api/v1/post/_STORY_ID_/";
         /* StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
              @Override
              public void onResponse(String s) {
                  gson = new Gson();
                  mapPost = (Map<String, Object>) gson.fromJson(s, Map.class);
                  mapTitle = (Map<String, Object>) mapPost.get("title");
                  mapContent = (Map<String, Object>) mapPost.get("content");

                  post_content.setText(mapTitle.get("name").toString());
                  post_contentHTML.loadData(mapContent.get("description").toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8");

                  //  progressDialog.dismiss();
              }
          }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
              @Override
              public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                  // progressDialog.dismiss();
                  Toast.makeText(PostViewActivity.this,id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
          });

          RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(PostViewActivity.this);
          rQueue.add(request);*/
    } else {
        post_contentHTML.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        WebSettings webSettings = post_contentHTML.getSettings();
        post_contentHTML.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

      //  post_contentHTML.addJavascriptInterface(post_contentHTML,post_contentHTML);
          post_contentHTML.loadUrl("http://www.asiannews.co.in/bp4a-api/v1/post/_STORY_ID_/");
        post_contentHTML.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        post_contentHTML.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        post_contentHTML.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        post_contentHTML.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
        post_contentHTML.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
          post_contentHTML.getSettings().getMixedContentMode();
        post_contentHTML.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
          post_contentHTML.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
          post_contentHTML.loadDataWithBaseURL(" ",post_con,"text/html","utf-8"," ");
        post_contentHTML.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
        post_contentHTML.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        post_contentHTML.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
            {
                // Handle the error
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                post_contentHTML.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                        "document.getElementsByClassName('adsbygoogle')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                        "})()");
            }
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

              view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
            });
      //  post_contentHTML.loadUrl(URL);

        // post_contentHTML.loadData(html,"text/html","utf-8");
        // post_contentHTML.loadUrl("http://asiannews.co.in/myads.html");

         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
              webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(false);
              webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(false);
          }

    }

    post_author = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.post_author);


    postImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    profilePic = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePic);


    //Setting up Post Image and Toolbar Activity
    //final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    /*ViewCompat.setTransitionName(postImageView, TAG_SEL_POST_IMAGE);

    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) postImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    Palette.generateAsync(bitmap, new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
        public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
            applyPalette(palette, postImageView);
        }
    });*/


    //Setting Up Post Admob Banner
    ////Standard Banner
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

    if (Const.ADMOBService_ACTIVE) {
        //----------Exit Ad----------------------------------
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.unit_id_interstitial));
        AdRequest adRequestInterstitial = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequestInterstitial);
        //----------Exit Ad----------------------------------

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded();
                mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    } else {
        mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    getPost();

}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private void initActivityTransitions() {
    if (Utils.isLollipop()) {
        Slide transition = new Slide();
        transition.excludeTarget(android.R.id.statusBarBackground, true);
        getWindow().setEnterTransition(transition);
        getWindow().setReturnTransition(transition);
    }
}

private void applyPalette(Palette palette, ImageView image) {
    int primaryDark = getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_dark);
    int primary = getResources().getColor(R.color.primary);
    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(primary);
    Utils.setStatusBarcolor(getWindow(), primaryDark);
    initScrollFade(image);
    ActivityCompat.startPostponedEnterTransition(this);
}

private void initScrollFade(final ImageView image) {
    final View scrollView = findViewById(R.id.scroll);

    setComponentsStatus(scrollView, image);

    scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {
            setComponentsStatus(scrollView, image);
        }
    });
}

private void setComponentsStatus(View scrollView, ImageView image) {
    int scrollY = scrollView.getScrollY();
    image.setTranslationY(-scrollY / 2);
    ColorDrawable background = (ColorDrawable) toolbar.getBackground();
    int padding = scrollView.getPaddingTop();
    double alpha = (1 - (((double) padding - (double) scrollY) / (double) padding)) * 255.0;
    alpha = alpha < 0 ? 0 : alpha;
    alpha = alpha > 255 ? 255 : alpha;

    background.setAlpha((int) alpha);

    float scrollRatio = (float) (alpha / 255f);
    int titleColor = getAlphaColor(Color.WHITE, scrollRatio);
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(titleColor);
    toolbar.setSubtitleTextColor(titleColor);
}

private int getAlphaColor(int color, float scrollRatio) {
    return Color.argb((int) (scrollRatio * 255f), Color.red(color), Color.green(color), Color.blue(color));
}

/**
 * It seems that the ActionBar view is reused between activities. Changes need to be reverted,
 * or the ActionBar will be transparent when we go back to Main Activity
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private void restablishActionBar() {
    if (Utils.isLollipop()) {
        getWindow().getReturnTransition().addListener(new TransitionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {
                toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                toolbar.setSubtitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                toolbar.getBackground().setAlpha(255);
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    restablishActionBar();
    if (Const.ADMOBService_ACTIVE) {
        displayInterstitial();
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        restablishActionBar();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private void getPost() {
    //Requesting The Story
    String url = null;
    url = Const.URL_STORY_PAGE.replace("_STORY_ID_", selectedPostID.replace("P", ""));
    //Log.i(TAG, "Taging: " + url);
    // making fresh volley request and getting json
    JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            //Log.i(TAG, "Taging: " + response.toString());
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
            if (response != null) {
                try {
                    if (response.has("error")) {
                        String error = response.getString("error");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        parseJsonFeed(response);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException es) {
                    es.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), es.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    }) {
        /** Passing some request headers **/
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            headers.put("ApiKey", Const.AuthenticationKey);
            return headers;
        }
    };

    // Adding request to volley request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
}


private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject feedObj) {
    try {
        objTitle = feedObj.getString("name");
        post_name.setText(Html.fromHtml(objTitle));

        commentsCount = feedObj.getInt("comments");
        if (feedObj.getString("can_comment") == "no") {
            user_can_comment = false;
        }

       if (!Const.ShowPostAsWebView) {
            post_contentHTML.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            URLImageParser p = new URLImageParser(this, post_content);
            spannedContent = Html.fromHtml(feedObj.getString("story_content"), p, null);
            post_content.setText(trimTrailingWhitespace(spannedContent));
        } else {

            post_content.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            post_contentHTML.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            post_contentHTML.loadData(html,"text/html","utf-8");

            String post_con = "<!DOCTYPE html>" +
                    "<html lang=\"en\">" +
                    "  <head>" +
                    "    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">" +
                    "  </head>" +
                    " <body>"+ "<script>" +
                    "<ins>" +"</ins>" +
                    "</script>"+"<script>"+
                    "</script>"
                    +"#content" +
                    "  </body>" +
                    "</html>" ;
            try {
                InputStream in_s = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.post_format);
                byte[] b = new byte[in_s.available()];
                in_s.read(b);
                post_con = new String(b);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            post_con = post_con.replace("#title#", feedObj.getString("name"));
            post_con = post_con.replace("#content#", feedObj.getString("story_content"));

            post_contentHTML.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");
            post_contentHTML.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,
                    post_con,
                    "text/html",
                    "UTF-8",
                    null);
        }

        if (feedObj.getString("story_content").length() <= 0) {
            post_content.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            post_contentHTML.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        post_author.setText(feedObj.getString("author"));
        getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("By " + feedObj.getString("author"));

        post_image = feedObj.getString("image");
        objURL = feedObj.getString("url");

        if (Const.Analytics_ACTIVE) {
            AnalyticsUtil.sendEvent(this, "Post View", objTitle, objURL);
        }

        //Setting Up a Share Intent
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, objTitle + " - " + objURL);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via"), 300);
            }
        });

        //setShareIntent(shareIntent);

        //Comment Button Click
        Button viewComments = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnViewComments);
        commentsNumber = Utils.formatNumber(commentsCount);
        viewComments.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.comments_button), commentsNumber));
        viewComments.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClass(PostViewActivity.this, PostComments.class);
                i.putExtra("post_id", selectedPostID.replace("P", ""));
                i.putExtra("post_title", getIntent().getStringExtra(TAG_SEL_POST_TITLE));
                i.putExtra("commentsCount", commentsCount);
                i.putExtra("user_can_comment", user_can_comment);
                startActivityForResult(i, 1000);
            }
        });

        //Button Click
        Button viewWeb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnViewWeb);
        if (Const.ShowPostOnExternalBrowser) {
            viewWeb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewWeb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    goToUrl(objURL);
                }
            });
        }


        // Converting timestamp into x ago format
        CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                Long.parseLong(feedObj.getString("timeStamp")),
                System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
        timestamp.setText(timeAgo);

        profilePic.setImageUrl(feedObj.getString("profilePic"), imageLoader);


        loadConfig();
        //pbLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //llayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private void goToUrl(String url) {
    Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(url);
    Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
    startActivity(launchBrowser);
}

private void loadConfig() {
    if (post_image != null) {
        ViewCompat.setTransitionName(postImageView, TAG_SEL_POST_IMAGE);
        Picasso.with(this).load(post_image).into(postImageView, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) postImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                new Palette.Builder(bitmap).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
                    public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
                        applyPalette(palette, postImageView);
                    }
                });
                /*Palette.generateAsync(bitmap, new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
                    public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
                        applyPalette(palette, postImageView);
                    }
                });*/
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {

            }
        });
    } else {
        postImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}


@JavascriptInterface
public void resize(final float height) {
    PostViewActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Trigger: " + height + " // " + (int) (height * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //post_contentHTML.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int) (height * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density)));
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    post_contentHTML.loadUrl("javascript:Asiannews.resize(document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height)");
}

public static CharSequence trimTrailingWhitespace(CharSequence source) {

    if (source == null)
        return "";

    int i = source.length();

    // loop back to the first non-whitespace character
    while (--i >= 0 && Character.isWhitespace(source.charAt(i))) {
    }

    return source.subSequence(0, i + 1);
}

// Invoke displayInterstitial() when you are ready to display an interstitial.
public void displayInterstitial() {
    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
        interstitial.show();
    }
}


public class URLImageParser implements Html.ImageGetter {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    class URLDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
        // the drawable that you need to set, you could set the initial drawing
        // with the loading image if you need to
        protected Drawable drawable;

        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
            // override the draw to facilitate refresh function later
            if (drawable != null) {
                drawable.draw(canvas);
            }
        }
    }

    class ImageGetterAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable> {
        URLDrawable urlDrawable;

        public ImageGetterAsyncTask(URLDrawable d) {
            this.urlDrawable = d;
        }

        @Override
        protected Drawable doInBackground(String... params) {
            String source = params[0];
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(source);
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                Picasso pic = new Picasso.Builder(mContext).build();
                bitmap = pic.load(uri).get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
            return new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), bitmap);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
            // set the correct bound according to the result from HTTP call
            urlDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + result.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0
                    + result.getIntrinsicHeight());

            // change the reference of the current drawable to the result
            // from the HTTP call
            urlDrawable.drawable = result;

            // redraw the image by invalidating the container
            URLImageParser.this.mView.invalidate();
        }
    }

    private final Context mContext;
    private final View mView;

    public URLImageParser(Context context, View view) {
        mContext = context;
        mView = view;
    }

    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(source);
        URLDrawable urlDrawable = new URLDrawable();
        ImageGetterAsyncTask task = new ImageGetterAsyncTask(urlDrawable);
        task.execute(source);
        return urlDrawable;
    }
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(PostViewActivity.this).reportActivityStart(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(PostViewActivity.this).reportActivityStop(this);
}
}
```

How can I do that?
What am I doing wrong?